# magento2 run sql query display Single and double quotation

Tags: magento2, sql

Direct SQL Query in Magento 2

```
   $sql = "UPDATE ".$table." SET `value` = '".$newMetaTitleValue."' WHERE  value_id = ".$id;
 $connection->query($sql);
```

dispaly result

```
xception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Sky-ukeydeal' WHERE  value_id = 9718' at line 1, query was: UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar SET `value` = 'No Man's Sky-ukeydeal' WHERE  value_id = 9718
Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Sky-ukeydeal' WHERE  value_id = 9718' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

```
 $sql = "Update " . $your_table_name . "Set column_name = '.$your_value.' where entity_id = ".$id;
```

Comment: yes,   I tryed ,it will dispaly error                                                                                 
            .UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar SET `value` = '.No Man's Sky-ukeydeal.' WHERE value_id = 9718

Comment: Please share your code for update query

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');

$connection = $resource->getConnection();

$tableName = $resource->getTableName('employee');

$sql = "Update " . $tableName . "Set emp_salary = 20000 where emp_id = 12";

$connection->query($sql);`